# Limit length of a bendy bone?

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, constraints

I am rigging some hair with Bendy Bones with the method found in this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BsJ3Grq_3GM

I can control the hair by moving/rotating the tail bone. However, this allows me to stretch it. I would like to limit the length of the bendy bone so that it can still move and rotate, but never stretch the hair past its original length.

I can use Limit Distance constraint on the tail to stop it from stretching too far, but that does not take into account length caused by rotation of the head, and doesn't stop the length from getting compressed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the constraints setup, that will solve the issue. I used naming convention from the tutorial, so constraints visible on the image are added to the tail bone.[image]